# How to avoid creating new models when saving complex objects

Tags: java, android, ormlite

My mobile device gets data from an API server and the result sets can get very complex. Here is an example of the structure being returned:

```
{
    "Home" : {
        "Person" : [
            {
                "name" : "Joe",
                "age" : 16,
                "gender" : "Male",
                "occupation" : null
            }, {
                "name" : "Jane",
                "age" : 23,
                "gender" : "Female",
                "occupation" : {
                    "position" : "Barista",
                    "years" : 4,
                    "type" : "Temporary"
                }                                
            }, {
                "name" : "Samantha",
                "age" : 7,
                "gender" : "Female",
                "occupation" : null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is just ONE object. Where in this case I have created 2 models:

`Home` & `Person`...BUT there is another object within `Person` called `Occupation` but I refuse to create a model for this.

The current way I persist this data is that I persist the `Person` Object first since I will define it as a Foreign entity of `Home` and then when I save the `Home` object, I will use the reference of the `Person` to persist my Home object.

Is there a way to avoid doing all of this? Can I just have one model called `Person` instead while being able to persist all the inner objects?

Is it a bad idea to create another Model for small object that probably has only one or two properties inside?

Comment: I don't think it's a bad idea if your app needs to access nested json. This makes sure that you map correctly one by one with result data. But if you want to reduce models in json tree, you can parse only needed properties and put them into custom model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Home & Person...BUT there is another object within Person called Occupation but I refuse to create a model for this.

Why do you refuse?  There is little to no penalty for doing so and a lot of benefits of encapsulation.  Your JSON is treating `occupation` as a class given the `{ ... }` and so should you in Java.

For example, if you instead tried to embed the fields from `occupation` in `Person`, how would a `null` occupation field be represented?  Would it be setting all of the fields to be `null` and `0`?  Then how would the following be represented?

```
"occupation" : {
    "position" : null,
    "years" : 0,
    "type" : null
}
```

This is a hack a best.

> Is it a bad idea to create another Model for small object that probably has only one or two properties inside?

Certainly not.  It is the right thing to do.  I would use some sort of json -> Java converter and just create your `Person` to match the JSON, field by field.  The time you take to work on your data model will be repaid when you work with the object and your representation matches your model completely.

Comment: Yup, sorry for the delayed response. I did in fact end up using another Model for smaller objects. I also crated an inner model within a model which I'm not sure is the right thing to do but it's working. I created a model called `Person` and in that model, I created an inner class called `Occupation`.